# Why is 礼 honorific in 「お礼を申し上げます/give my thanks [to someone]」?

Tags: keigo

In 謙譲語 the addition of honorific to a direct object depends on who owns it:

> （先生に）本をさしあげます。| I will give teacher my book
>
> （先生の）ご本をお借りします。| I shall borrow teacher's book
>
> （先生を）会場へご案内します。| I will show teacher to the meeting place

There are some words that always take an honorific (examples discussed in other questions include お茶 and お手洗い）but 礼 is not one of them.  Why are "my" thanks honorific but not my book?

(I imagine that in Japanese they are not "my" thanks, or their is a difference between tangible/intangible objects/gestures, but these are guesses.)

Comment: They are indeed "my" thanks, but お serves more functions than just distinguishing between grammatical person. It's often just a word beautifier. Here's a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keigo#Honorific_prefixes

Comment: @Bily: Thanks I've tightened up the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the お is simply there to make it sound more polite and is more a part of 丁寧語 than a part of 謙譲語. I would consider the classification of your third example as follows.

> 口語体　案内するよ。
>   文語体　案内します。
>   丁寧語　ご案内します。
>   謙譲語　ご案内致します

with increasing level of politeness.

> ご連絡差し上げます。

would be another example of you "giving" something and adding a polite お or ご.

Comment: Re: 丁寧語=ご案内します, my reference is 完全文法N３　p５３ divides 謙譲語　into "Verb forms used to describe the speaker's behaviour when it involves/affects a superior" (including my example w/します）and "Verb forms used to describe the speaker's own behaviour politely or modestly" (and has a new example with 致します）.